# How to make scatterplot with geom_jitter plot reproducible?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I am using the Australian AIDS Survival Data. This time to create scatterplots.

To show the genders in survival of different Reported transmission category (T.categ), I plot the chart in this way:

```
data <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vincentarelbundock/Rdatasets/master/csv/MASS/Aids2.csv")

data %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_jitter(aes(T.categ, sex, colour = status))
```

It shows a chart. But each time I run the code, it seems to produce a different chart. Here are 2 of them putting together.

[image]

Anything wrong with the codes? Is it normal (each run a different chart)?

Comment: geom_jitter needs set.seed to make it reproducible. Try `set.seed(1); data %>% ...`

Comment: @zx8754, thank you! is there a rule setting the seeds? by the way, would you put it as an answer?

Comment: No, you can use any number, I prefer 1, some prefer 42 :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try setting the seed when plotting:

```
set.seed(1); ggplot(data, aes(T.categ, sex, colour = status)) +
  geom_jitter()
```

---

From the manual `?geom_jitter`:

> It adds a small amount of **random** variation to the location of each point, and is a useful way of handling overplotting caused by discreteness in smaller datasets.

To have that "random variation" reproducible, we need to set `set.seed` when plotting.

Answer (score 24):

if you use `geom_point` instead of `geom_jitter`, you can add `position = position_jitter()`, which accepts the seed argument:

```r
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(as.factor(cyl), disp)) 

p + geom_point(position = position_jitter(seed = 42))
```

[image]

```r
p + geom_point(position = position_jitter(seed = 1))
```

[image]

And back to "42"

```r
p + geom_point(position = position_jitter(seed = 42))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

If we want to make something random, yet reproducible for permutations etc., we can use *sample* to set the seed:

```
my.seed = sample(1:10000,1)
set.seed(my.seed)
```

Then we can use it to write a filename such as:

```
save(my_plot, paste0('plot', my.seed, '.rda')
```

Comment: Is there a theoretical/citable reason for why this would give more/better "randomness" than just using 1:10000 directly as the seeds?